# Retrofit returns null response body when issuing a GET request

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using retrofit to receive JSON data from my API. I am able to receive the JSON data when the data contains a single object. But when I try to a get list of all the employees I get an error.

JSON data for /api/Employee/1 is (working fine):

```
{
  "id": 10,
  "name": "Arpit",
  "number": "7777777777",
  "city": "noida",
  "depid": 4,
}
```

Code to get this JSON object is working. PFB the code.

Retrofit Code:

```
public void onResponse(Response<EmployeeResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (response.raw().toString()!=null) {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(response.body().id);
        e.setName(response.body().name);
        e.setCity(response.body().city);
        e.setNumber(response.body().number);
        Log.d("employee details", e.toString());
        list.add(e);
        rv.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(list));
    }
    else
        Log.d("No data recieved",response.raw().toString());
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    Log.d("Fail",t.getMessage());}
```

EmployeeAPI.java

```
public interface EmployeeAPI {
@GET("/assignment1/api/Employee/1")
Call<EmployeeResponse> load_employee();}
```

EmployeeResponse.java

```
public class EmployeeResponse {
@SerializedName("id")
public String id;
@SerializedName("name")
public String name;
@SerializedName("city")
public String city;
@SerializedName("number")
public String number;}
```

But when I am trying to get the list of all Employees from /api/Employee I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

JSON data for api/Employee is ():

```
[  
   {  
  "id":10,
  "name":"Arpit Jain",
  "number":"7777777777",
  "city":"noida",
  "depid":4,
   },
   {  
  "id":32,
  "name":"Ish Chawla",
  "number":"9999999999",
  "city":"Noida",
  "depid":1,
   },
   {  
  "id":39,
  "name":"Laxman",
  "number":"6666666666",
  "city":"GZB",
  "depid":1,
   },
   {  
  "id":44,
  "name":"Ishan",
  "number":"9839060055",
  "city":"Kanpur",
  "depid":3,
   }
]
```

Code to get the list of employees is:

Retrofit Code

```
public void onResponse(Response<EmployeeResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (response.raw().toString()!=null) {
        Log.d("employee details", response.body().toString());
        list = response.body().list;
        rv.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(list));
    }
    else
        Log.d("No data recieved",response.raw().toString());
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    Log.d("Fail",t.getMessage());
}
```

EmployeeAPI.java

```
 public interface EmployeeAPI {
    @GET("/assignment1/api/Employee")
    Call<EmployeeResponse> load_employee();
}
```

EmployeeResponse.java

```
   public class EmployeeResponse {
    public ArrayList<Employee> list;
}
```

Kindly tell me the changes required to get the data correctly.

Comment: When multiple user you required List of EmployeeResponse. Better solutions is to get List of user means JSON ARRAY even there is one user.

Comment: what is baseurl?

Comment: @JaydeepPatel The Base URL is accessible only on our intranet. That is why I posted the whole JSON response in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of you are fetching whole employee list and its an Array.

```
  public interface EmployeeAPI {
     @GET("/assignment1/api/Employee")
     Call<Employee[]> load_employee();

     @GET("/assignment1/api/Employee/1")
     Call<Employee> load_employee();
    }
```

And Don't create EmployeeResponse class. Use @SerializedName in Employee pojo class.

After getting response

```
if (response.raw().toString()!=null) {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setId(response.body().id);
        e.setName(response.body().name);
        e.setCity(response.body().city);
        e.setNumber(response.body().number);
        Log.d("employee details", e.toString());
        list.add(e);
        rv.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(list));
    }
```

Dont need to set this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I removed the EmployeeResponse Class, made my POJO class serializable and just changed Call<EmployeeResponse> to Call<Employee[]>. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EmployeeResponse {
   @SerializedName("id") 
   public String id; 
   @SerializedName("name")
   public String name;
   @SerializedName("city")
   public String city;
   @SerializedName("number")
   public String number;
}
```

Make use of above class as model

```
public interface EmployeeAPI {
  @GET("/assignment1/api/Employee")
  Call<ArrayList<EmployeeResponse>> load_employee();
}
```

and since you return a list make call object accept a list to accept a list of employees

Comment: I tried this before posting the question. This method didn't work. Got the same error "Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change little in code:

1)**EmployeeResponse.java**

```
public class EmployeeResponse {
    public List<Employee> list;

      public List<Employee> getDatas() {
        return datas;
    }
  }
```

2) **Employee.java**

```
  public class Employee{
       @SerializedName("id") 
       public String id; 
       @SerializedName("name")
       public String name;
       @SerializedName("city")
       public String city;
       @SerializedName("number")
       public String number;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    }
```

3) **In Interface:**

```
public interface EmployeeAPI {
  @GET("/assignment1/api/Employee")
  Call<EmployeeResponse> load_employee();
}
```

4) **Retrofit Code**

```
 private void getEmployee() {
List<Employee> employee;
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        EmployeeAPI apiInterface = retrofit.create(EmployeeAPI.class);
        Call<EmployeeResponse> call = apiInterface.load_employee();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<EmployeeResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<EmployeeResponse> call, Response<EmployeeResponse> response) {
       employee = response.body().getDatas();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<EmployeeResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure:" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```